# Needing to mass export all exchange boxes into individual PSTs on exchange 2010

Tags: exchange

I'm not really an exchange admin, and I've tried using the

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Export-Mailbox -PstFolderPath c:\pstexport
```

commnand. Which errors out. It screams by and hits each mailbox and fails with the following.

```
Error was found for (the user mailbox) because: Error occured in a step: Approving object
An unknown error has occurred, error code -2147221219"
```

I added the user (administrator) to the

```
New-ManagementRoleAssignment -Role "Mailbox Import Export" -User administrator
```

If I do it wrong let me know. I've just been following guides like from [this site here](http://www.exchangemaster.net/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=151&Itemid=1&lang=en)

I really need to get this started tonight so it can be done sometime tomorrow. Until then I'm going to be exporting one at a time through the GUI into outlook then exporting to pst (which is slow and horrible doing it manual)

Comment: What's the rush? Why do you have to do this? What's the goal? *(I'm thinking a little more context can help us give better answers.)*

Comment: Cripes, those directions are horrible. They're using the Outlook interface to pull e-mail into a PST file. Do not use `Export-Mailbox` if you can help it. Use the MailboxRequest commandlets and do not install Outlook or any part of Office on an Exchange server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tested, works in the Exchange Management Shell:

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | ForEach-Object { New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $_.Identity -FilePath ("\\localhost\c$\pstexport\" + $_.Alias + ".pst") }
```

Use `Get-MailboxExportRequest` to monitor the status of the process, it will take a while if the mailboxes are large.

Use `Remove-MailboxExportRequest` to cleanup afterward (use `-Status Completed` to cleanup while still in process).

Comment: ForEach-Object : The term 'New-MailboxExportRequest' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,
or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
 again.
At line:1 char:51
+ Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | ForEach-Object <<<<  { New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $_.Identity -FilePath "D
:\PSTFiles\" + $_.Alias }
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (New-MailboxExportRequest:String) [ForEach-Object], CommandNotFoundExcep
   tion

Comment: 1. Do you have the EMS open? 2. Are you *sure* this is Exchange 2010?

Comment: Yes I'm sure its Exchange 2010. Yes, I was using Exchange Management Shell.

Comment: You're running 2010 RTM. You need to install SP1, SP2, or SP3... You're dangerously behind on updates.

Comment: I'm trying to solve someone elses problem so I'm not really an exchange administrator. We're converting over this domain into another environment and I'm just trying to solve this problem. It seems you're right so I'm going to run these updates right now, thanks a ton.

Comment: This worked, the issue was specifically not having SP1. Thanks so much for leading me to this fix. Mailboxes have been exporting all night. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This is a permissions related error. To correct this issue, use following steps:

1. Use EMC to add the user account to Exchange Server administrator role on the source & target server.
2. Add user account to Local Administrators group on the source
   and target server.
3. Use Add-MailboxPermission command in EMC to grant full access to the mailbox on source & target server.